# Why the macro "ZVAL_COPY_VALUE(z,v)" seems to work unexpectedly in PHP Internal?

Tags: hashtable, php-internals

**My question is about HashTable:**

The PHP VERSION debugged is PHP-7.0.12, I couldn't find out where the zval's **str** member is updated within the macro **"ZVAL_COPY_VALUE(z, v)"** when I add one new string, however it indeed updated successfully by GDB tracing the macro context, that is to say, the zval's **str** member within the **Bucket** struct indeed had got the string address.

Expand the macro then finally get the code as follow:

```
zval *_z1 = z; 
const zval *_z2 = v; 
zend_refcounted *_gc = (*_z2).value.counted      
uint32_t _t = (*_z2).u1.type_info;
uint32_t _w2 = _z2->value.ww.w2; 
(*_z1).value.counted = _gc;
_z1->value.ww.w2 = _w2;
(*_z1).u1.type_info = _t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`zend_value`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/71301f5baf1e746e9414b351bf140508d965f37d/Zend/zend_types.h#L285) is a union type, which means that all members share the same starting address. Copying both `value.counted` and `value.ww.w2` copies the whole `zend_value` structure. It does not matter which of the members is actually in use at the time.